# How to use math functions on numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, math

I have the following numpy array:

```
x=np.linspace(1,10,20)
```

I tried applying a mathematical function on it:

```
y=x**3-4*x**2+30
```

It worked as expected and generated an array. However, when I try using a `math` function it does not seem to work:

```
y=math.sin(x)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How can I apply the function on the array efficiently (without having to use a loop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the numpy equivelent. [`numpy.sin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sin.html):

```
y = np.sin(x)
```